# Term for an "almost regular" sequence

Tags: terminology, reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring (commutative, with unit), $M$ an $R$-module, and $x_1, \dotsc, x_n \in R$.  Consider the following two conditions:

1. For all $i$, the homomorphism $$\frac{M}{(x_1, \dotsc, x_{i-1})M} \stackrel{x_i}{\longrightarrow} \frac{M}{(x_1, \dotsc, x_{i-1})M}$$ is injective.
2. $$\frac{M}{(x_1, \dotsc, x_n) M} \neq 0.$$

Taken together, these conditions give the definition for the $x_i$ to form an $M$-regular sequence.  However, it is sometimes useful to consider Condition 1 by itself.  For instance, this comes up in Eisenbud, *Commutative Algebra*, Exercise 6.7 (page 174 in my copy).  Eisenbud sort of, but not really, calls such a sequence an "(almost) regular sequence."

> Is there a standard term (or, for that matter, any reasonable term with a not-too-obscure reference) for a sequence of elements of $R$ (possibly contained in some fixed ideal of $R$, especially if $R$ is local) that satisfy Condition 1, but not necessarily Condition 2?

(Other related notions of "not-quite-regular sequence" would also be of interest.)

Comment: I will just note that the term "almost regular has been taken": http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.mmj/1220879428

Answer (score 7):

A reasonable term with a not-too-obscure reference: that is called a *weak $M$-sequence* by Bruns and Herzog in *Cohen-Macaulay Rings* (p. 3 in the edition I have).

Comment: This is certainly a valid reference (+1). The trouble is, based on google searches, that "weak M-sequence" is more commonly used to refer to a sequence in which condition (i) is replaced by the condition that everything annihilating $x_i$ annihilates your entire ideal (e.g., your maximal ideal, if $R$ is local).